# How To Create An Incrementing FloatingActionButton View?

Tags: android, view, floating-action-button

In my app i get a value which is certain number of pages,according to this value i need to create a certain number of FloatingActionButtons on click of a parent `menu` `FloatingActionButton`(Like in the below image).

[image]

There are `libraries` that can create such a `view` but cannot increment the view according to my value. OnClick of each small `FloatingActionButtons` i need to navigate onto separate pages.

How to create such an incrementing `view` ?

Comment: You looking for floating action menu many tutorials are there to [refer](https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton) [refer](http://www.viralandroid.com/2016/02/android-floating-action-menu-example.html)

Comment: @Mohamed Mohaideen AH-In this library can we add more fabs like in a incrementing manner according to a value.

Comment: Yes see menus_fragment.xml file you can add more views.

Comment: If you want number of floating buttons at runtime create view programmatically as per needs and add it to root layout

Comment: @ Mohamed Mohaideen AH - i did everything but the labels wont show up did u have any trouble with it.Will you please help me

Comment: Add wat you tried with required code so we can find & fix the issue better.

Comment: i got it anyway thanks man for responding....